# how to add all child in map as a list in trigger handler?

Tags: apex, trigger, null-pointer

On Entity__c object on that have Event as a related list. i want when i change the owner of the Entity then Owner of the Event also get change. for this i write the trigger on after update.but from UI when i change the owner then i get error null pointer exception.Here is my code :-

```
    public static void afterUpdateEntity(List<Entity__c> listOfEntity,Map<id,Entity__c> mapOfOldEntity){
      List<Event> listOfEventToUpdate = new List<Event>();
      set<id> setOfEntity = new Set<id>();
      if(!listOfEntity.isEmpty()){
         for(Entity__c entity : listOfEntity ){
            if(mapOfOldEntity != NUll && mapOfOldEntity.get(entity.id).OwnerId != entity.OwnerId){
                setOfEntity.add(entity.id);
            }
         }
   }
  System.debug('setofentity-->>' + setOfEntity);

  List<Entity__c> listOfEntityEvent = [select id,Name,OwnerId,(select id,OwnerId from Events) from Entity__c where id in : setOfEntity];
  System.debug('listOfEntityEvent-->>' +listOfEntityEvent);

  // NOw get all events related to entity
 List<Event> listOfEvent = [select id,OwnerId,WhatId from Event where WhatId in : setOfEntity];
 System.debug('listOfEvent--->>' + listOfEvent);

 Map<Id,List<Event>> mapOfEntiyEvent = new Map<id,List<Event>>();
 List<Event> listOfEvents ;
 for(Entity__c e : listOfEntityEvent){
      listOfEvents = mapOfEntiyEvent.get(e.id);
      if(e.events != NUll){
          listOfEvents.add(e.events);
          mapOfEntiyEvent.put(e.id, listOfEvents);
      }
 }

  System.debug('mapping--->>' + mapOfEntiyEvent);
}
```

i didn't know how to solve this. i am getting error on listOfEvents.add(e.events); this line.Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is something like this, you don't have to do validations:

```
public static void afterUpdateEntity(List<Entity__c> listOfEntity,Map<id,Entity__c> mapOfOldEntity){

    Map<id,Entity__c> mapOfEntity = new Map<id,Entity__c>(listOfEntity);
    // Query all related events
    List<Event> listOfEvent = [select id,OwnerId,WhatId from Event where WhatId in :mapOfEntity.keySet()];
    for(Event e : listOfEvent)
        e.OwnerId = mapOfEntity.get(e.WhatId).OwnerId;

    update listOfEvent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
Map<Id,List<Event>> mapOfEntiyEvent = new Map<id,List<Event>>();
List<Event> listOfEvents ;
for(Entity__c e : listOfEntityEvent){
    listOfEvents = mapOfEntiyEvent.get(e.id);
    if(e.events != NUll){
        listOfEvents.add(e.events);
        mapOfEntiyEvent.put(e.id, listOfEvents);
    }
}
```

the `mapOfEntiyEvent` starts out empty so will result in `listOfEvents` being null.

This pattern of having a map where the key is an Id and the value is a list is quite common, and the trick is to create new instances of the list as you go or just use the list that is already there if it has already been created:

```
Map<Id,List<Event>> mapOfEntiyEvent = new Map<id,List<Event>>();
for(Entity__c e : listOfEntityEvent){
    List<Event> listOfEvents = mapOfEntiyEvent.get(e.id);
    if (listOfEvents == null) {
        listOfEvents = new List<Event>();
        mapOfEntiyEvent.put(e.id, listOfEvents);
    }
    if (e.events != null) {
        listOfEvents.add(e.events);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You @Keith C. i tried your code but still i am getting error that list has more  than one rows for assign the sobject error. In actual i am  getting error because in listOfEntityEvent  i am not gettind events, as i am quering them but still not getting in result so that's y it is always giving me null list.

Comment: @SalesforceFolks I answered what you asked; there may be other logic errors or code errors that you will have to work through.